# Reference request for Poisson Geometry.

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, poisson-geometry

I was searching for an introductory text on Poisson geometry.I have tried searching it and end up getting -

http://www.math.illinois.edu/~ruiloja/Math595/book.pdf

and after looking at a similar question in MSE I got this one but that is advanced for me though - Lectures on the Geometry of Poisson Manifolds by Izu Vaisman
https://books.google.com/books?id=z1r2BwAAQBAJ&pg=PR5&lpg=PR5

But I am a begineer in this and I know Hamiltonian ,Lagrangian . Any one can suggest some good reference so that I can have grasp and can appreciate Poisson geometry.

Comment: I like the book "Poisson Structures" by Vanhaecke, Pichereau, and Laurent-Gengoux.

Comment: @Nick does the book also deal with quantization?

Comment: @ChoMedit Sort of...the last chapter is about "deformation quantization". But that is only the last chapter of a 400-page book. And the book has a very algebraic (as opposed to geometric) point-of-view, so it may not be the most standard treatment of quantization.